# Serve static context jboss as 7.1 outside of webcontext

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jboss

Question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543936/load-the-image-from-outside-of-webcontext-in-jsf/4543951#4543951), sadly the answer is not Jboss specific.

This recent [post](http://jojovedder.blogspot.com/2012/11/configuring-static-resources-in-jboss.html), and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8575964/1341526) have lead me to the conclusion that there are 3 ways of achieving this in Jboss AS 7:

1. A custom [servlet](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html).
2. Add a Jboss [Module](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToPutAnExternalFileInTheClasspath).
3. Just install another webserver like Apache/Nginx.

Which are the pros/cons of each one?

The specific purpose is to serve images stored in the file system that were previously uploaded by users.

Comment: Where's **your** question here? Just a bunch of links up there

Comment: @jacktrades: I am the author of jojovedder.blogspot. In Jboss 7 the module was the only configurable method, instead of coding anything like a custom servlet

Comment: @JoseK: I've read your blog, but it seems to only configure external folders to be available in the runtime classpath (by `ClassLoader#getResource()` and so on), not by a public web URL (which is ultimately what the OP is asking for and what "serve static resources" stands for). Or are they really available by a public web URL?

Comment: @JoseK edited it to make it clearer

Comment: @BalusC: Nope - not via direct web URL