# Openshift: how to show image from DATA_DIR?

Tags: java, servlets, openshift

According to this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/24264878/2382770][1] answer (it's no accepted) I try read image file from OpenShift DATA_DIR but get message in browser:

> Image «http://app-name.rhcloud.com/GetImageServlet?img=681265.jpg»
>   can not be shown since contains errors."

```
@WebServlet("/GetImageServlet")
public class GetImageServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String fileName = request.getParameter("img");
        String uploadFilePath = ...;
        System.out.println(uploadFilePath);

        byte[] imageBytes = getImageAsBytes(uploadFilePath);
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        response.setContentLength(imageBytes.length);
        response.getOutputStream().write(imageBytes);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

    public byte[] getImageAsBytes (String ImageName) throws IOException {
         // open image
         File imgPath = new File(ImageName);
         BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(imgPath);

         // get DataBufferBytes from Raster
         WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage .getRaster();
         DataBufferByte data   = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();

         return ( data.getData() );
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

Do we realy can get data from OpenShift DATA_DIR ?

Comment: I am not completely sure, but I would guess that when you get byte[] from image raster, you get RAW data. But you want to send image encoded as jpeg => read the file from data directly (standard fileinputstream) instead of using imageio api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only mistake you made is that you send RAW image data (as read by `ImageIO`). Change the `getImageAsBytes()` method to read directly image data from file as they are (e.g. jpeg files contains image encoded in jpeg format) using standard `FileInputStream`. Alternatively, you can use '[Files.readAllBytes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes-java.nio.file.Path-)(..)' to read content of file.